# Why is this BJT Schmitt trigger producing a sine wave?

Tags: transistors, rf, oscillator, schmitt-trigger

I am trying to build a Schmitt trigger from a pair of BJTs to convert a sine to a square wave.

The sine wave is from a [Colpitts oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colpitts_oscillator) running at over 150 MHz. I want to measure the frequency using something like the SN74LV4040, which is why I want to square the sine wave somewhat.

This is the relevant part of the Schmitt trigger (with V1 representing the oscillator). Emitter current was set to 2 mA, high voltage to 3 V, low voltage to 2 V.

[image: Schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWcaEh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But this is the output I get in LTspice.

[image: Sine wave output from Schmitt trigger]

Why am I getting a sine wave output from the Schmitt trigger?

This is the whole schematic (with some voltages plotted), if that helps:

[image]

Comment: 150MHz isn't what 74 series capable of.

Comment: Page 6 of the SN74LV4040 datasheet indicates a typical f(max) of over 200MHz. Is there another family that you'd recommend?

Comment: What happens if you run the simulation at a much lower frequency? Say, 50kHz?

Comment: Ah... Thankyou. It worked well at 1MHz

Comment: @talikarng You should check "switching characteristics"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kilo-ohms and over 100 MHz!  You cannot get anything rectangular looking due the time constants caused by the parasitic capacitances, which can easily be 10 pF or more.

Comment: Thankyou. It worked when I ran the simulation at much lower frequencies.